# Why does Spring Boot with embedded H2 throw a 'org.h2.message.DbException' error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I'm doing a simple Spring Boot & embedded H2 tutorial with Eclipse/STS on a MacBook.

It works fine when I use H2 as memory only, my `application.properties` file looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

But I want to persist the database to a file (so that the data is not lost when app is shut down).

When I make this change to write DB to the disk:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/data/demo
```

I get this error on startup:

```
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/data/demo.trace.db", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file ""/data"" [90062-200]" [90034-200]
```

What am I doing wrong?

More details from the stack trace:

```
2020-11-09 12:33:24.246  INFO 15139 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/data/demo.trace.db", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file ""/data"" [90062-200]" [90034-200]
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/data/demo.trace.db", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file ""/data"" [90062-200]" [90034-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.logWritingError(TraceSystem.java:294)

[...]

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Log file error: "/data/demo.trace.db", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file ""/data"" [90062-200]" [90034-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: Error while creating file "/data" [90062-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.createDirectory(FilePathDisk.java:290)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectory(FileUtils.java:43)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectories(FileUtils.java:315)
    at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.openWriter(TraceSystem.java:305)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Error while creating file "/data" [90062-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    ... 95 more
```

Comment: At first glance, looks like some problem with permissions for writing a file to disk.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to write to `/data/demo` and not e.g. `./data/demo` (note the `.`) or just `data/demo`? The former would attempt to write to the root directory, for which your application almost surely lacks the necessary write permissions.

Comment: Thanks @DmitriyPopov -- your permissions idea got me looking closer at the directories and permissions, and it turns out the problem was I needed "./data/demo" with a "."

Comment: Thanks @user991710 -- you were right, the problem was I needed "./data/demo" with a "."  Cheers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution was I needed a `.` like this `./data/demo`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/demo
```

Comment: Just to note: `./` means that that the directory or file thereafter is relative to the *current working directory* of the application. For an embedded database (which H2 usually is used as, at least in Spring), this should be fine. For a dedicated database you would have a fully qualified JDBC string which is the address of the DBMS that is listening for incoming connections.